# Node.js - promises in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the this problem to handle nested promises and loops:

```
firstPromise().then(function(resultOfFirstPromise){
    var promiseArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      var ret = secondoPromise();
      promiseArray.push(ret);
    }
    return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}, function(error){
    console.log("firstPromiseError");
}).then(function(resultOfSecondPromise){
    console.log(i); //but obviously i = 10
}, function(error){
    console.log("secondPromiseError");
});
```

What I want to do is to have the loop index value `i` in every `.then`  of each secondPromise: the output of my code should by somthing like this:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

Comment: just use  (let i = 0) instead (var i=0) if you can use ES6. Also in your code snippet  does not shown how you use  i.

Comment: Use `promiseArray.push(Promise.resolve(i));` and then `resultOfSecondPromise` will be an array of numbers from 0 to 9.

Comment: You need to resolve your promise with `i` if you want to use it in your `then` function.

Comment: This feels like you've simplified the problem for the question, which is generally a good thing, but could you explain more about why you need to do this? there may be another way of going about the problem.

Comment: yes, i agree with @dougajmcdonald it is unclear why you need to use an index of the for loop of another scope, where you normally shouldn’t be able to reach at all.

Comment: besides check your codes indentation and bracket-matching.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with `Promise`. In the chain of `.then()`, one `.then()` is run only after all of its previous `.then()` are done. Meaning, if a `.then()` has finished running, it will never run again.

I don't know your use case but what you are trying to do is achievable using [`Rxjs/Observables`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    Rx.Observable.from(arr)
        .do((v) => {
            /*do some thing*/
            console.log(v)
        })
        .do((v) => {
            /*do another things*/
            console.log(v)
        });
```

In above code callback inside each `do()` will run for each element of the `arr`.

`Output`:

```
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 3
 4
 4
 5
 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chain the `then` calls to `secondoRomise()`, and also use `let` in the loop:

```
firstPromise().then(function(resultOfFirstPromise){
   var promiseArray = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     var ret = secondoPromise();
     promiseArray.push(ret);
     ret.then(result => console.log("Promise No." + i + " returned " + result);
   }
   return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}).then(() => console.log("all done!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a scope problem because when you create a new function, it creates a new scope so you can't access one scope from another, it acts sort of like creating a new class in Javascript. This is the exact same reason when you create a function you often have to create a variable to reference this (e.g. const self = this). You can get around this using the ES6 arrow functions, since it doesn't create a new class/scope when you use them.

```
firstPromise().then( (resultOfFirstPromise) => {
    var promiseArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      var ret = secondoPromise();
      promiseArray.push(ret);
    }
    return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}, (error) => {
    console.log("firstPromiseError");
}).then( (resultOfSecondPromise) => {
    console.log(i); //but obviously i = 10
}, (error) => {
    console.log("secondPromiseError");
});
```

Something like that, you may need to finagle a little bit.